# "cut a hole in the suit", "bore a hole in the suit with a scissor" or something else?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language, phrasal-verbs

"cut a hole in the suit", "bore a hole in the suit with a scissor" or something else?

> She cut a hole on the suit using a scissor.

Originally, it was supposed to be "cut a hole on", but I am not sure, because I can't find anyone using this phrase. I see "in" the suit, but to me it's nonsensical, since you're making a cut on the fabric and not in the fabric.

Comment: Is this a sentence you found somewhere, or one that you're writing yourself?  Because we almost always say "make a hole **in**", never "make a hole **on**".   *On* sounds like "on top of the surface of", which doesn't make any sense for a hole.

Comment: And it's always _a pair of scissors_.

Comment: @KateBunting - except in Wales.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Go on?

Comment: @JamesK when I was twenty I was friends (never more, to my regret) with a lovely trainee teacher from Cardiff who used to say 'a scissor' (I can still hear her say it. She looked like the Lady of Shallott in the painting), and she said it was common then, although dying out (this was 50 years ago)

Comment: I was told by an American friend that some Americans in Wisconsin, and maybe elsewhere, say 'a scissor', and sometimes 'a tweezer' and 'a clipper'. However, as with the Welsh singular usage, these are severely regional and non-standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Bore" is used for the act of *drilling* a hole in something. That is not the action of a pair of scissors. Scissors *cut*.

Also, scissors are always plural. The correct name is *a pair of scissors*, but many just say 'scissors'.

So, the correct way to phrase what you are trying to say would be:

> She cut a hole in the suit using (a pair of) scissors.